# Stream audio with Amazon Echo

Tags: streaming, amazon-echo

I know this has to be possible because Spotify and Pandora provide support but I can't see it documented anywhere. Does anyone else know how these skills support audio streaming? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update: As of today (August 24, 2016), the Alexa Skills Kit now supports audio streaming:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx1DSINBM8LUNHY/New-Alexa-Skills-Kit-ASK-Feature-Audio-Streaming-in-Alexa-Skills